# To temporarily hold the borrowed object

Tags: rust, mutability, borrow-checker, borrowing

```
struct Parent<'a> {
    inner: Option<&'a mut Object>
}
impl<'a> Parent<'a> {
    fn new() -> Parent<'a> {
        Parent {
            inner: None,
        }
    }
    fn bind(&mut self, obj: &'a mut Object) {
        self.inner = Some(obj);
    }
    fn unbind(&mut self) {
        self.inner = None;
    }
}
struct Object {
    inner: u32,
}
fn main() {
    let mut obj = Object { inner: 0 };
    let mut parent1 = Parent::new();
    let mut parent2 = Parent::new();
    parent1.bind(&mut obj);
    parent1.unbind();
    // parent2.bind(&mut obj);
    // ^ error

}
```

Struct `Parent` field must store the `Option`:

```
struct Parent {
    inner: Option</*  magic  */>
}
```

It is necessary to temporarily block the possibility of working with the object in `fn main()`, until you call the `.unbind()`

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @T3H40 How to necessary to temporarily block the possibility of working with the object in `fn main()`, until you call the `.unbind()`?

Comment: it's impossible. The object is bound until you drop parent1: http://is.gd/8alczd

Comment: @T3H40 If the object is already binded to the other parent, you can not interact with it. As I started using crutches `&mut`. http://is.gd/RD7DSz

Comment: There's absolutely no way to get what you want at compile-time, since there's no way to specify that the `unbind` function frees up the borrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible for the borrow checker to prove this correct at compile-time. But you can use `RefCell` to make sure it works at runtime and panics if you do it wrong. Instead of storing a reference to the object in the Parent object, you can store a `RefMut` that allows you to modify the object. The `bind` function takes a reference to a `RefCell` and will panic if the object is already borrowed.

```
use std::cell::*;

struct Parent<'a> {
    inner: Option<RefMut<'a, Object>>,
}
impl<'a> Parent<'a> {
    fn new() -> Parent<'a> {
        Parent {
            inner: None,
        }
    }
    fn bind(&mut self, obj: &'a RefCell<Object>) {
        self.inner = Some(obj.borrow_mut());
    }
    fn unbind(&mut self) {
        self.inner = None;
    }
}
struct Object {
    inner: u32,
}
fn main() {
    let obj = RefCell::new(Object { inner: 0 });
    let mut parent1 = Parent::new();
    parent1.bind(&obj);
    parent1.unbind(); // comment this line out and you get a runtime panic
    let mut parent2 = Parent::new();
    parent2.bind(&obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also scope the usage of `parent1`. Since once you bind `obj` to `parent2`, it cannot be used by `parent1` anymore:

```
let mut obj = Object { inner: 0 };
{
    let mut parent1 = Parent::new();
    parent1.bind(&mut obj);
    parent1.unbind();
}
let mut parent2 = Parent::new();
parent2.bind(&mut obj);
```

Comment: It's the other way around. "Since you cannot access `parent1` after the scope is closed, the borrow checker knows that `parent1` cannot access `obj` anymore, so you can access `obj` again.